# Compilation error when plot and subplot are inserted

Tags: captions, compiling

I am trying to add subtables inside tables. To achieve that I add the following packages:

```
\usepackage[format=plain,labelfont=bf,up,textfont=it,up]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
```

After adding these the compilation gives

```
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/psfrag/psfrag.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/tools/theorem.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/tools/thp.sty)))

! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package caption.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
...                                              

l.13 \usepackage
            {subcaption}
?
```

The packages added before that are:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                               %Allows input of tex files encoded in UTF8
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                            %Set font encoding for   output PDF 
\usepackage[danish,english]{babel}                    %Allows langauge switching (English is default)
\usepackage{graphicx}                                     %Support for including graphics
\usepackage{xcolor}                                 %Support for using colours  
\usepackage[hang,normalsize,bf]{caption}            %Make pretty captions
\usepackage{hyperref}                               %References package
\usepackage{varioref}                                       %Enhances references (\vref {label})
\usepackage{fancyhdr}                               %Pretty headers/footers
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,latexsym}               %AMS and other symbols
\usepackage{epic,eepic,epsfig,graphics,psfrag}      %Figure/picture packages
\usepackage{theorem}
```

Comment: You have  `\usepackage[hang,normalsize,bf]{caption} ` _and_  `\usepackage[format=plain,labelfont=bf,up,textfont=it,up]{caption}` you can't load caption with two sets of options. One or the other (or both at the same time)

Comment: You probably also don't want `epsfig` which was a compatibility wrapper around `graphicx` for a package popular in the 1980's and `hyperref` usually wants to be loaded last

Comment: thanks it would perfectly ... I must pay more attention before posting next time!